# Change resolution for an old Philips 109E5 monitor?

Tags: display, resolution, monitor

I have an old monitor Philips 109E5 19 inch and I need configuring a resolution of 1600x1200. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this script:

```
xrandr --newmode 1600x1200_60.00  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1600x1200_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1600x1200_60.00
```

and then I added it to Startup applications. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a tool for that under Settings - Screens.

[image]

[image]

But does your  monitor support that resolution?  If you're not sure you can try different resolutions with:

> xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768

Although it could be LVDS or VGA